# Using an integrating sphere to create near-point source

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Can I use an integrating sphere to turn a distributed light source (say, a 2-D array of 100 LEDs) into a near-point source (say, the size of a single LED)?  I realize that the 2-D array itself would absorb some of the light inside the sphere, and that the sphere's inner surface is not 100% reflective, resulting in further losses. But if I have 100 LEDs inside the sphere, each of which is 5mm in diameter and producing 1 milliwatt, can I get substantially more than 1 milliwatt of power from a 5mm exit aperture?

EDIT: Perhaps some elaboration would be helpful. An “integrating sphere” is an optical component consisting of a hollow cavity with its interior covered with a diffuse reflective coating, with small holes for entrance and exit ports. Light rays incident on any point on the inner surface are, by multiple scattering reflections, distributed equally to all other points. It is typically used with some light source and a detector for optical power measurement. You can buy them from several optical supply houses.
My question involves the scenario shown in the figure. If photons are injected from multiple LEDs situated around the perimeter, is the optical power emitted from the exit port approximately equal to the sum of the LED outputs?
[image]

Comment: you are probably better served by starting with  a 5mm LED die.  insetad of using 100 0.5mm LED dies encapsuleted in resin.  light cannot be intensified by optical means.

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/intensifying-a-light-source

Comment: I don't seem to be getting a lot of response here. Is there something I can do to make the question more clear?

Comment: @Jasen: The link you provided applies to imaging optics (lenses). The integrating sphere is a non-imaging optical device, and it's not clear that the same limitations apply.

Comment: If it were possible there would be a way to reverse the arrow of entropy.

Comment: Assuming a perfect integrating sphere  the light from each 5mm LED would reflect off on average 99 other 5mm LED  (and several more times off the sphere surface but it's perfect so there is no loss there) before finding the 5mm output aperture.  a perfectly reflective LED won't emit any light.