# Second law of thermodynamics does not seem to hold under radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

The Second law of Thermodynamics can be stated as heat always flows from hot to cold.

Consider the following system described in the image, where we have two parts A and B, at some time $t = 0$ we assume that both systems have equal temperature. That would imply no heat flow would occur. However, let us take an example where we would take two light bulb filaments at $T = 5000K$ then we would expect the filaments to radiate light outwards. Place both filaments in a vacuum in a mirror ball, with a hole that connects both mirror balls. Now all light emitted stays within the system.

Now rotating one filament would allow more light to be emitted to one ball, giving us a new temperature equilibrium. This would imply that system A could for example become $T_A=4000K$ and $T_B = 6000K$. That is heat flow occurred between two systems of the same temperature, a contradiction to the fact that heat always flows from hot to cold.

Would this experiment actually work or is there some part that is highly illegal?

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Related/Duplicate? - [intensifying a light source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/intensifying-a-light-source/10963#10963)

Comment: “*Now rotating one filament would allow more light to be emitted to one ball*” Why? And a raytracing figure with some light paths drawn and not others isn’t convincing. I could just as well draw rays from only the mirror backsides to the filaments to make it look like more radiation is impinging on filament B. In fact both filaments are always surrounded by radiation at 5000 K regardless of orientation.

Comment: @Farcher that indeed answers the question, though it does not feel intuitive that an ant can radiate as much energy to a star as the star can radiate to the ant. But that would imply two things, namely 1. that A starts emitting more radiation over a smaller area than B and 2. that chemical and nuclear reactions that heat up fire or the sun are "hot", nuclear reactions at least hotter than the temperature of the core of the sun $2*10^6 K$. Then the question is what it means for reaction to be hot, but that is a different question

Comment: @Chemomechanics Sure, but if I would have two configurations of one light bulb and 1 million light bulbs in parallel, the configuration of 1 million light bulbs directed at an object will heat it up faster than the single light bulb. So the point is that the same should happen in the picture, but according to Carl Brennen's answer Farcher redirected me to it should still only heat up as much as the heat of the lights.

Comment: “*the configuration of 1 million light bulbs directed at an object will heat it up faster than the single light bulb*” This is also incorrect for your setup. Inside the mirrored chamber you describe, every surface is already facing something at 5000 K. Something can’t be surrounded more than 100%. The confusion with increasing the power output occurs because you never specified how all this power is dissipated outside the chamber. Forgetting the power dissipation and consider only *objects* at 5000 K, two or 1,000,001 objects will stay at 5000 K.

Comment: Consider reviewing [conservation of etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue#Conservation).

Answer (score 0):

By the fundamentals of  thermodynamics, if the two matter pieces have the same temperature $T$, the vacuum is filled with Planks radiation field for that temperature. Each eigenmode of frequency $\omega$ is excited independenly with probability $e^{-\frac{n \hbar \omega}{k T}}$ normalized to unit probabilty in total. The field of modes aquire at each moment in the mean as many photons of energy $\hbar   \omega$ per mode from the matter pieces, as there are absorbed.

The electromagnetic mode fields and the the absorption and emission probabilities may change drastically with geometry or by isolating the surfaces of the matter pieces, changing the time to reach equilibrium. But the equilibrium  is always defined to be: Each quantum state in the vacuum field and in the solid state system is occupied by the probabilty of Boltzmann factor of equilibrium temperature.

The Bose fields of electromagnetic radiation in a mirrored volume, the phonon fields of the osciallating ions in the solid and the Fermi field of electron bands have very different probability distributions, but they all participate in the thermodynamic equilibrium game: energy packet emission probability per second equals emission probablity with Einsteins correction factor.

The fact, that absolute temperature in equilibrium can be defined for such physically different systems in thermal contact is a much more complicated theorem, than just a change of geometry by a rotation, that merely may change modes and the direct directional absortion/emission probabilities. For more details see e.g. wikipedia

[Kirchhofs law of radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation)